# UDP socket connected to DHT node, not recieving data

Tags: python, sockets, udp, bittorrent, dht

I'm attempting to implement the DHT protocol using python, but having troubles getting a response from a public DHT node (router.bittorrent.com:6881). Interestingly, the Node JS variant that I wrote works fine and I was able to get a response from the server. I'm using windows and added a UDP port rule in the inbound connections of the firewall settings that opened all UDP ports. I also tried disabling the entire firewall all together, but to no avail. I would appreciate any input.

```
#info_hash is a byte string parameter 

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.settimeout(3)

network_info = (socket.gethostbyname('router.bittorrent.com'), 6881)
sock.connect(network_info)



rand = lambda: ''.join([chr(random.randint(0, 255)) for _ in range(20)])
my_id = rand()
get_peers = {b"t":b'aa', b"y":b"q", b"q":b"get_peers",
            b"a": {b"id":my_id,
                  b"info_hash": info_hash}}

encoded_data = bencoding.encode(get_peers)
sock.send(encoded_data)
res = sock.recv(1024) #Always times out here
```

I added a firewall rule (and disabled all firewall protection measures in windows' settings), tried to bind the socket to (0.0.0.0), and attempted to use linux (kali linux virtual machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- for routing table maintenance/bootstrapping you should use `find_node`, not `get_peers`
- use wireshark to see what's being sent over the network and compare that with the working implementation
- check the firewall on your router
- use a bound UDP socket, not a connected one, you want local-to-any communication. This shouldn't be relevant for the first request but it's how a DHT node should be implemented
- bind to a single address, not 0.0.0.0. This is mostly relevant for multi-homed hosts but still good practice in general